# Unable to send message to remote ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in JBoss EAP 7.2

Tags: java-8, jms, activemq-artemis, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to send a JMS message to remote ActiveMQ Artemis queue that is embedded in JBoss EAP 7.2. I have defined the following in `standalone-full.xml`:

1. Remote Connector
2. Pooled Connection Factory
3. Remote binding

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:4.0">
    <server name="default">
        <journal pool-files="10"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <remote-connector name="ImportantMessages-remote" socket-binding="ImportantMessages-remote"/>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <jms-queue name="TestQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/TestQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="ImportantMessages-remote" entries="java:/jms/remoteIM" connectors="ImportantMessages-remote"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-config-smallrye:1.0"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-health-smallrye:1.0" security-enabled="false"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-opentracing-smallrye:1.0"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
    <bindings>
        <external-context name="java:global/remoteContext" module="org.apache.activemq.artemis" class="javax.naming.InitialContext">
            <environment>
                <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
                <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616"/>
                <property name="queue.ImportantMessages" value="ImportantMessages"/>
            </environment>
        </external-context>
        <lookup name="java:/ImportantMessages" lookup="java:global/remoteContext/ImportantMessages"/>
    </bindings>
    <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>
```

Below is my client program:

```java
public void sendObjectMessage() {
    Properties initialProperties = new Properties();
    initialProperties.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
    initialProperties.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://127.0.0.1:61616");
    try {
        context = new InitialContext(initialProperties);
        factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("java:/jms/remoteIM");
        destination = (Queue) context.lookup("java:global/remoteContext/ImportantMessages");
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        EventMessage eventMessage = new EventMessage("1", "Message from FirstClient");
        ObjectMessage objectMessage = session.createObjectMessage();
        objectMessage.setObject(eventMessage);
        connection.start();
        producer.send(objectMessage);
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + "has sent a message : " + eventMessage);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (context != null) {
            try {
                context.close();
            } catch (NamingException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the below exception:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: scheme java not recognized
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ReadOnlyContext.lookup(ReadOnlyContext.java:222)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.demo.sender.FirstClient.sendObjectMessage(FirstClient.java:41)
    at com.example.demo.controller.MessagingController.sendMessage(MessagingController.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone suggest me what wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to send a JMS message to remote ActiveMQ Artemis queue that is embedded in JBoss EAP you can use the default `standalone-full.xml`. You don't need to set up a remote connector, pooled connection factory, *or* remote binding. You simply need to lookup `jms/RemoteConnectionFactory` from your client using JBoss EAP JNDI context. To be clear, when ActiveMQ Artemis is embedded in JBoss EAP remote clients use the JBoss EAP JNDI context not the ActiveMQ Artemis JNDI context since EAP itself is in charge of all JNDI operations.

Your client is using the ActiveMQ Artemis JNDI context:

```java
initialProperties.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
initialProperties.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://127.0.0.1:61616");
```

This is incorrect. You should be using this instead:

```java
initialProperties.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
initialProperties.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
```

**Note:** You could also use `org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory` here because that class is also shipped with JBoss EAP 7.2. However, this class is really included for backwards compatibility with legacy clients.

Then your client is trying to lookup the `pooled-connection-factory` you configured in `standalone-full.xml`:

```java
factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("java:/jms/remoteIM");
```

This is also incorrect. A `pooled-connection-factory` can *only* be used by clients running in the same JVM as JBoss EAP (e.g. an MDB which needs to send a message). You can't simply look it up from a remote client and expect to get pooling. That's not how it works. You should be doing this instead:

```java
factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
```

This will use the default `connection-factory` in `standalone-full.xml` named `RemoteConnectionFactory`.

Then you're looking up a queue which isn't even defined in the messaging subsystem (i.e. `java:global/remoteContext/ImportantMessages`). You've apparently configured it in an `external-context` for some reason. This is wrong for EAP. You should define this in your `standalone-full.xml`:

```xml
<jms-queue name="ImportantMessages" entries="java:jboss/exported/ImportantMessages"/>
```

And then use this in your client:

```java
destination = (Queue) context.lookup("ImportantMessages");
```

Ultimately, this is what your messaging subsystem in `standalone-full.xml` should look like:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:4.0">
    <server name="default">
        <journal pool-files="10"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <jms-queue name="ImportantMessages" entries="java:jboss/exported/ImportantMessages"/>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>   
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

You don't need the `external-context` you've configured.

Lastly, this is what your client should ultimately look like:

```java
public void sendObjectMessage() {
    Properties initialProperties = new Properties();
    initialProperties.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
    initialProperties.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
    try {
        context = new InitialContext(initialProperties);
        factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
        destination = (Queue) context.lookup("ImportantMessages");
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        EventMessage eventMessage = new EventMessage("1", "Message from FirstClient");
        ObjectMessage objectMessage = session.createObjectMessage();
        objectMessage.setObject(eventMessage);
        connection.start();
        producer.send(objectMessage);
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + "has sent a message : " + eventMessage);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (context != null) {
            try {
                context.close();
            } catch (NamingException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JBoss EAP has a bunch of "quickstart" applications available to demonstrate how to use its features. Here is the [JMS "Hello World" quickstart](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/7.2.0.GA/helloworld-jms) which you might find useful for reference.

If you're building your client application with Maven then this is the dependency you should be using:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.eap</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Also, keep in mind that ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in JBoss EAP 7.2 is secured by default so you will either need to disable security in the messaging subsystem (e.g. using `<security enabled="false"/>`) or add a user to the `ApplicationRealm` (e.g. via the `bin/add-user.sh` script) and pass the proper credentials when you [create your connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html#createConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: When I gave the InitialContextFactory as org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory, it gave me a ClassNotFoundException. I changed the InitialContextFactory to org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory, added jboss-remote-naming and xnio jar files to classpath. Now it is throwing javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080]

Comment: Now I am able to lookup the ConnectionFactory and Queue, but while sending message to the queue, I am getting javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: AMQ119031: Unable to validate user from /127.0.0.1:51568. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable

Comment: Thanks Justin. I will try to add security to JBoss EAP 7.2 AMQ and add a separate question if it does not work.

Comment: I have posted a fresh question related to sending message https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59918017/javax-jms-jmsexception-failed-to-create-session-factory-while-sending-message-t. Would you like to have a look at it?