# javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory while sending message to embedded ActiveMQ Artemis within JBoss EAP 7.2

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to develop a program that will send message to ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in JBoss EAP 7.2. I have followed the instructions given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59696449/unable-to-send-message-to-remote-activemq-artemis-embedded-in-jboss-eap-7-2/59696698?noredirect=1#comment105550901_59696698):

Below is my method which sends a message:

```java
public void sendMessage() {
    Context context = null;
    ConnectionFactory factory = null;
    Destination destination = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;

    Properties initialProperties = new Properties();
    initialProperties.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
    initialProperties.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://<<EXTERNAL-IP>>:8080");
    initialProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "mquser");
    initialProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Mquser@123");
    try {
        context = new InitialContext(initialProperties);
        factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
        System.out.println("Lookup Success");
        destination = (Destination) context.lookup("jms/queue/TestQueue");
        System.out.println("Queue lookup success");
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        String text = "Test Message";
        TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage();
        textMessage.setText(text);
        connection.start();
        System.out.println("Going to send");
        producer.send(textMessage);
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + "has sent a message : " + text);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (context != null) {
            try {
                context.close();
            } catch (NamingException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have created the Application User `mquser` with password `Mquser@123`. I have disabled security in `standalone-full.xml`. Below is what the messaging subsystem looks like in `standalone-full.xml`:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:4.0">
    <server name="default">
        <journal pool-files="10"/>
        <security enabled="false"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <jms-queue name="TestQueue" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/TestQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>   
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

Below are the  and  section of standalone-full.xml

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <socket-binding name="iiop" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
    <socket-binding name="iiop-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

I am starting jboss using the below command

```
sh standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full.xml -b <<INTERNAL-IP>> -bmanagement <<INTERNAL-IP>>
```

With these, I was able to successfully send message to MQ in one of my environment but in another environment it is failing with the below exception:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:846)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:282)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:277)
    at com.mycompany.springdb.service.MessagingService.sendMessage(MessagingService.java:45)
    at com.mycompany.springdb.controller.DateController.sendMessage(DateController.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:797)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:844)
    ... 58 more
```

In the line `connection = factory.createConnection();` Can anyone suggest me is there anything wrong with the program or is there something wrong with the environment or what might be the problem?

Comment: @JustinBertram I have updated my question with the full messaging subsystem section of standalone-full.xml. Is anything else required?

Comment: @JustinBertram I have added the <Interfaces> and <socket-binding-group> section of standalone-full.xml and also the command I am using to start jboss. Please note that when starting jboss, I am using the Internal IP address of my server and while looking up the administered objects in JNDI, I am using the External IP address of my server.

Comment: If you're binding the server to an internal IP address then how is the JNDI lookup working given that it's using the *external* IP address? Do you have some kind of NAT going on?

Comment: I am not sure about the networking details but the ConnectionFactory and the Queue are successfully looked up in the JNDI. The exception is thrown only while creating the Connection object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `-b` switch on the command-line when starting the server that means all the socket-bindings in your `socket-binding-group` will be bound to that IP address by default.

Your JMS client is looking up `jms/RemoteConnectionFactory`. Here's the configuration for that `connection-factory`:

```xml
<connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
```

This `connection-factory` is using the `http-connector`. Here's the config for the `http-connector`:

```xml
<http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
```

This is using the `http` `socket-binding` which is using the internal IP address since you're using the `-b` switch on the command-line when starting the server. Therefore when your remote JMS client looks up `jms/RemoteConnectionFactory` it will get a connection factory pointing to the *internal* IP address which will fail.

To resolve this issue you need to configure `RemoteConnectionFactory` to use the external IP address.

First, define a new `interface`, e.g.:

```xml
<interface name="external">
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.external:<<EXTERNAL-IP>>}"/>
</interface>
```

You can configure the actual external IP address here or you can pass it on the command-line using `-Djboss.bind.address.external=<<EXTERNAL-IP>>`.

Second, define a new `socket-binding` to use this interface:

```xml
<socket-binding name="external" interface="external" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
```

Third, define a new `http-connector` to use this `socket-binding`:

```xml
<http-connector name="http-connector-external" socket-binding="external" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
```

Fourth, change `RemoteConnectionFactory` to use this `http-connector`:

```xml
<connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector-external"/>
```

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned but jboss is throwing an exception during startup. The exception says "failed to resolve interface external"

Comment: If I give the internal IP address (private IP) in the interfaces section instead of External IP (public IP), it is not throwing any exception but I am getting the error as originally posted in the question. Is it something I will have to modify at network level?

Comment: The problem got resolved, the NAT configuration was wrong which we needed to change. Thanks. I will raise a new question about enabling security as I was not able to solve that area and disabling security in standalone-full.xml

Comment: Just for reference, I had to add a new outbound socket binding entry and use the newly created socket binding in http connector as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757922/how-to-connect-to-jms-queue-jboss-eap-7-behind-nat